# Setting Table's body height in tbody

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I am trying to fix the table's body height and make them scrollable. Basically I have 3 tables, 2 of them I want on top, side by side and third one should be below them.
I want to make the table body height fixed(say 300px) but I am unable to make this effect. I tried various ways but most of them are destroying table layout look.
This is my code-

```
<div id="DashboardTab" style="display: table-layout;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <div id="" style="float: left; width: 50%; ">  
                    <legend>Planned</legend>
                    <table id="ePlanned"">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Col1</th>
                                <th>Col2</th>
                                <th>Col3</th>
                                <th>Col4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody><!-- style="height: 300px; overflow: auto">--><!--tried this and other ways but not working-->
                            <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="" style="float: right; width: 50%;">
                    <legend>Closed</legend>
                    <table id="eClosed" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Col1</th>
                                <th>Col2</th>
                                <th>Col3</th>
                                <th>Col4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                <legend>Stats</legend>
                <table id="uStats" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="102.5%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Col1</th>
                            <th>Col2</th>
                            <th>Col3</th>
                            <th>Col4</th>
                            <th>Col5</th>
                            <th>Col6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and also I made the 3rd table width to 102.5% so it gets aligned to above two table but I know its not good practice.
Can anyone please help me this I have also wasted lots of time.
I want my page to be like below picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the wrapper `div` for each table on `overflow:auto` and set a fixed `height` for each table.

This is a possible solution:

```html
<div id="DashboardTab" style="display: table-layout;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <div id="" style="float: left; height:100px; width: 50%; overflow: auto;">  
                    <legend>Planned</legend>
                    <table id="ePlanned">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Col1</th>
                                <th>Col2</th>
                                <th>Col3</th>
                                <th>Col4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="" style="float: right; height:100px;  width: 50%; overflow: auto;">
                    <legend>Closed</legend>
                    <table id="eClosed" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Col1</th>
                                <th>Col2</th>
                                <th>Col3</th>
                                <th>Col4</th>
                            </tr>
       <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr>
                                <td>MX1</td>
                                <td>MX2</td>
                                <td>MX3</td>
                                <td>MX4</td>
                            </tr>
       
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="" style="display: inline-block; height:100px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                <legend>Stats</legend>
                <table id="uStats" class="display" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Col1</th>
                            <th>Col2</th>
                            <th>Col3</th>
                            <th>Col4</th>
                            <th>Col5</th>
                            <th>Col6</th>
                        </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>MX1</td>
       <td>MX2</td>
       <td>MX3</td>
       <td>MX4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>MX1</td>
       <td>MX2</td>
       <td>MX3</td>
       <td>MX4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>MX1</td>
       <td>MX2</td>
       <td>MX3</td>
       <td>MX4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>MX1</td>
       <td>MX2</td>
       <td>MX3</td>
       <td>MX4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>MX1</td>
       <td>MX2</td>
       <td>MX3</td>
       <td>MX4</td>
      </tr>
       
      
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: here you are putting div into scrollable block which is not my aim basically i just want table body to be scrollable. every time column attribute should be visible which is not in your case

Answer (score 0):

Use display:flex .It makes your work easier

```css
#DashboardTab {
  display: flex;

  margin:20px;
}
.item{
width:50%;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
#DashboardTab table{

}
#DashboardTab table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
#table3 {
  display: flex;

  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content:center;
}
#table3 div {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 50px;
}
#table3 table,
tr,
td {}
```

```html
<div id="DashboardTab">
  <div class="item">
    <legend>Planned</legend>
    <table id="ePlanned">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
          <th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- style="height: 300px; overflow: auto ">-->
        <!--tried this and other ways but not working-->
        <tr>
          <td>MX1</td>
          <td>MX2</td>
          <td>MX3</td>
          <td>MX4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <legend>Closed</legend>
    <table id="eClosed ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
          <th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>



<div id="table3">
  <div>
    <legend>Stats</legend>
    <table id="uStats " class="display " cellspacing="0 " width="102.5% ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
          <th>Col4</th>
          <th>Col5</th>
          <th>Col6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want tables to take half of the space which is not happening in your answer, i had tried this. I want my page to look good by creating same size table

Comment: You mean all the tables should take half of the space